# I am getting a parse error while using jq in the below json output

Tags: amazon-web-services

Error: parse error: ':' not as part of an object at line 2, column 13

Dont know where i am doing wrong can someone help me.

```
[
    "Events": [
        {
            "InstanceEventId": "instance-event-0d59937288b749b32",
            "Code": "system-reboot",
            "Description": "The instance is scheduled for a reboot",
            "NotAfter": "2019-03-15T22:00:00.000Z",
            "NotBefore": "2019-03-14T20:00:00.000Z",
            "NotBeforeDeadline": "2019-04-05T11:00:00.000Z"
         }
    ]
]
```

Comment: You need to tell us the jq command that's causing the error.

Comment: cat file-name | jq I am not even filtering anything. At the first place it self it is geeetting failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not a valid JSON remove the named array "events"

```
[
    [
        {
            "InstanceEventId": "instance-event-0d59937288b749b32",
            "Code": "system-reboot",
            "Description": "The instance is scheduled for a reboot",
            "NotAfter": "2019-03-15T22:00:00.000Z",
            "NotBefore": "2019-03-14T20:00:00.000Z",
            "NotBeforeDeadline": "2019-04-05T11:00:00.000Z"
         }
    ]
]
```

or remove the outer array

```
{
"Events": [
        {
            "InstanceEventId": "instance-event-0d59937288b749b32",
            "Code": "system-reboot",
            "Description": "The instance is scheduled for a reboot",
            "NotAfter": "2019-03-15T22:00:00.000Z",
            "NotBefore": "2019-03-14T20:00:00.000Z",
            "NotBeforeDeadline": "2019-04-05T11:00:00.000Z"
         }
    ]
}
```